# Divider not working in my listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to use a gradient divider in my simple listview. But it simply will not work.

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wood_small"
    android:padding="5dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/masthead_image" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:src="@drawable/tavi_mh_copy">
    </ImageView>

    <ListView  android:id="@+id/station_list" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/black_white_gradient" android:dividerHeight="2px">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Divider Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#00222222"
      android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
      android:endColor="#00222222"
      android:angle="0" />
</shape>
```

Comment: @Programmer Please, use code block by indenting the entire code block by 4 spaces (ctrl + K or use the code button on the toolbar). You won't have to escape the angled brackets this way.

Comment: @Yi Jiang I've encountered a few oddities using that feature.  So, I've just been wrapping the code in tags and escaping html when necessary, as I've seen others do.  I'll see if I can get the preferred approach to behave.

Comment: OK. I made this one look good using the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.Not exactly sure why it is working but I recreated the same layout and it started working. Maybe it was the position of the stars or something.

Thanks everyone,
Droidment